# Hadoop can not setTime to a directory, why?

Tags: hadoop

I'm running into a Hadoop issue.When I run my Hadoop testing program for changing the access time and modify time of a directory which on the hadoop file system,some errors occured. And I have no idea about it. So,hope for anyone's any useful advice.

Comment: First place to start - line 3 of the error log: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /hdfs/file does not exist.

Comment: Sorry, I did not describe it clearly. File /hdfs/file and directory /hdfs/dir have existed. But,the error still occured. Thank you anyway ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most versions of **Hadoop** it is indeed **not possible to set the times of a directory**. See this Hadoop ticket for the details [HDFS-2436](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-2436). The ticket will tell you what version you need to do that.

Note however that Hadoop does not support access times for directories at all, as far as I know.